# The edit button is moving the footer in tag search

Tags: feature-request, bug, tag-search, footer

So I was browsing some [unpopular tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?page=1323&tab=popular) when I noticed that the footer was moving.

If I hover over some of the  tags at the bottom of the page, an edit link appears. And the footer gets pushed down. Moving the mouse off the tag moves the footer back up.

I think the edit link only appears when the tag is not a synonym.

I think that this must be a bug because when I head over to [new tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?page=2&tab=new), hovering shows the edit link without the footer moving at all.

It's not a huge problem, but it's super annoying when you do notice it happening.

(Note: Since animuson commented that this is intended behavior, I have added [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) just in case.)

Comment: This is how it's supposed to work. The only real alternative to make that not happen is to display a "0 asked this year" line for those kinds of tags, so that the edit link doesn't create a new line in the box.